# Is there a PPA for commonly used non-free software?

Tags: ppa

I'm looking for a PPA to easily install packages like Skype, Google Chrome and other commonly used non-free software. Does such a PPA exist?

Please note that I'm not looking for `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: That would defeat the "personal" in PPA and would make it a repository and that is what `ubuntu-restricted-extras` is for.

Comment: It's not a PPA, but you could check out the Canonical Partner Repository, which contains several non-free programs.

Comment: @Rinzwind: True, but it would be very handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such PPA, but there are numerous PPAs you need to browse and install various free and non-free applications that do not exist in official repositories.

For some you may even need to go to their website to download and install a .DEB package.

However, there's a handy tool to search applications in all PPAs, add them to your **Software Sources** and install various packages, and it is **Y PPA Manager**, which you can install entering these commands in **Terminal**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

For more info about **Y PPA Manager**: [www.webupd8.org/2013/06/y-ppa-manager-099-released-with-support.html](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/y-ppa-manager-099-released-with-support.html)

And there is also **Ubuntu Tweak** which can be helpful in easily installing some common free and non-free apps. You can install **Ubuntu Tweak** entering these commands in **Terminal**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

For more info about **Ubuntu Tweak**: [www.webupd8.org/2013/04/download-ubuntu-tweak-084-now.html](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/download-ubuntu-tweak-084-now.html)